# Proving $ \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_{i} \text{ is finite.} $ by Induction.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, induction

> Prove : If $A_{1},A_{2},...,A_{n} \text{ are finite sets, then }  $$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_{i} \text{ is finite.} $$

Proof:

**(I)** Basis Step : $p(1)$ is true because it is true because it is finite. There is a first one and a last one.

**(II)**  Induction Step: Suppose $p(k)$ is ture.

$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^k A_{i} \text{ is finite.} $$

Show : $P(k+1)$ is true LHS.

$$ \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} A_{i} \text{ is finite.} $$

Here is where I get stuck because I do not know what the right hand side of this problem is. I also do not know if you are to multiply or add to the original left hand side. How does one prove this is true for all $n \in \Bbb N ?$

Comment: Hint $\left \vert \bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1} A_{i} \right\vert \leq \left\vert \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} A_{i} \right\vert + | A_{k+1}|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{k+1} A_i = [\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k A_i] \cup A_{k+1}$$ Since $p(k)$ is true, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k A_i$ is finite.  Since $p(2)$ is true (i.e. the union of two finite sets is finite), so is $p(k+1)$.

I want to point out that if $A_1, ... , A_n$ are sets, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n A_i$ doesn't necessarily make sense.  In order to take the union of a bunch of sets, they must all be subsets of some larger set.

Comment: Why is $p(2)$ true? How does it follow inductively from the fact that $p(1)$ is true? Observe that showing that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_{i}$ is finite is logically equivalent to showing that for any to finite set $A$ and $B$, $A\cup B$ is finite. But if there is to prove inductively that $p(2)$ is true if $p(1)$ is true, then you are *not* using induction to prove the proposition, you are proving it independently.

Comment: Fine, prove $p(1), p(2)$ then use induction for $k \geq 3$.

Comment: Yes. You need to prove $p(2)$ independently. Just a small correction, though. In your statement I think you wanted to mean "...prove $p(1),p(2)$ then use induction for $k≥\color{red}{2}$." because otherwise you need to show that $p(3)$ is true. Isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The induction step breaks down to:

Let $X = \cup_{i=0}^n A_i$; a union of $n$ finite sets that is, by assumption finite.

Let $Y = A_{n+1}$; a finite set.

So $\cup_{i=0}^{n+1} A_i = X \cup Y$; the union of two finite sets.  Suffices to show the union of two finite sets is finite.  Which is so absolutely obvious we just know it's going to be hard to prove.

Let $a_1,......, a_n$ be a finite indexing of set $X$.  Let $b_1..... b_m$ be a finite indexing of set $Y$.  Let $c_1........ c_{n+m}$ be such that if $i \le n$, $c_i = a_i$ and if $i > n$ then $c_i = b_{i-n}$.  Then $c_1...c_{n+m}$ is an indexing that accounts for, possibly with some redundancy, a complete indexing of $X \cup Y$.

So $X \cup Y$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by multiplying or adding anything. You need to show that

$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i$$
is finite. In particular
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{k+1}A_i=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k}A_i\right)\bigcup A_{k+1}$$
and thus you have the union of two finite sets.

Depending on your definition of finite, this may be all you have to say (i.e. the union of two finite sets is finite, so we are done). Formally, you could form a bijection from the set to a bounded set of natural numbers, but that may be overkill depending on context.

Comment: @Eliot G I was just thinking about when one is working with product and sigma notation. So by what you say above would it then be true for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: Yes this is the idea of induction. Induction basically says that if its true for two sets, it is true for arbitrarily many sets.