# Prove that if $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are finite sets, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ is finite.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Let, S be a set defined such that $ S =\{n \in \mathbb{N}:$ if $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are finite sets, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ is finite$ \} $.

Let n = 1 and assume $A_n = A_1 $ is finite. Then, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} =A_1$,which means $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} =A_1$ is finite. Therefore, $1\in S$. Suppose for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $n \in S$. Then, the predicate if $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are finite sets, then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n} A_{i}$ is finite is true for $n$. Suppose, $A_{n+1} $ is finite. Then, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} A_{i} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}  \cup A_{n+1}$. Since, $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}$ is finite by our induction hypothesis and since $A_{n+1}$ is finite, it follows that  $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1} A_{i}$ is finite. Therefore, $n+1 \in S$. By the principle of induction it follows that $S= \mathbb{N}$

please critique my proof and give any advice. Thank you!

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862603/proving-bigcup-i-1n-a-i-text-is-finite-by-induction) was asked yesterday--in the same class or just a coincidence?

Comment: A coincidence. The text I'm using is "Transition to Advanced Mathematics" for self study.